# Solar IC BQ25798 battery charger

Tags: lithium-ion, solar-cell

I am intending to implement a solar system that works on a single li-ion battery.

I want my li-ion battery to power my device and the solar system to charge my Li-ion battery.

Can I achieve this function with the [BQ25798](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25798.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1662559961014&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F)?

I know that the solar system won't deliver steady stable power supply, so I'm asking if this IC will deliver power from the  battery to the load independent of the input solar supply voltage and whenever the solar supply voltage is available it will charge the battery.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community my question is obvious and specific, I think

Comment: @SiefEldin how does your design differ from that in figure 9-1 of the datasheet? If it doesn't, then the answer is yes it'll work. If it does differ, how?